# How to configure codeigniter with site files in xampp?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, localhost

I've recently taken over a project from another developer, let's call it EBAY. I'm struggling to get their live site up and running on my local server for testing and debugging. They've built a web app using CodeIgniter. In their file manager on cPanel they've placed the ci folder at the root, not in the public_html folder.

I've copied their public_html files and their ci folder into my xampp's htdocs folder. The issue is that the site only loads when the ci folder is placed WITHIN the folder for EBAY. Oherwise when I load the localhost site it gives an error message that it cannot find the codeigniter folder inside EBAY folder.

How is this? How can the application run with the ci folder at the root on the live site, but when I have migrated it to the htdocs of xampp it is expecting the ci folder to be inside the EBAY folder?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of configuration is quite common nowadays, and if you look at Linux or Pear you'll discover that PHP files sometimes are completely in other directories than the webserver.
The ideas behind this are pretty simple but effective:

1. Any files can't be reached from the network / internet.
   So they can't be altered, downloaded or even just viewed.
2. PHP (or other) Libraries are clearly separated from individual code and can't be easily mixed up or accidentally be deleted.
3. Access rights are easier to control and perhaps even that differently than the files  in the webfolder.

Ok, so far an explanation. Now about your issue with it:
You've currently a webfolder `htdocs` in Xampp and in general you can use a subfolder as the webfolder and in htdocs directly you place the project files that are not public. You've to adjust then where the domain is pointing (docroot and/or virtual hosts).